# $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^2(z-1/2)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Calculate: $$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^2(z-1/2)^2}dz$$

the integral is equal to $$\int_{|z|=\frac{1}{4}}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^2(z-1/2)^2}dz+\int_{|z-\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{10}}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^2(z-1/2)^2}dz$$

for the first I use the cauchy formula for the function $f(z)=\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(z-1/2)^2}$ which is holomorphic in the disc $|z|<1/4$ and we get $f'(0)=4\pi=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=\frac{1}{4}}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^2(z-1/2)^2}dz$ ,  and we get $$\int_{|z|=\frac{1}{4}}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^2(z-1/2)^2}dz=8 \pi ^2 i$$
the same for the other one but with the function $g(z)=\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^2}$

Is my logic correct ?

Comment: Maybe you can choose some proper contour and use residue theorem?

Comment: i am not familiar with that theorem what does $Res$ mean ?

Comment: Cauchy residue theorem. As @JwJJJJ hints, that's exactly what you want to use here. Worth studying deeply and memorizing.

Comment: yes but i don't know that theorem can someone answer me if this logic is correct?

Comment: Good luck in your future endeavors, whatever your career might be.

Comment: @Aruralreader    What ? are you trolling me, i just want an answer if this work or not, what's wrong with that ?

Comment: @user from theory we can split the integral if we take the curves centered at the problematic points

Comment: Yes, your logic is correct with respect to equating the integral of interest to the sum of the integrals that you wrote.

Comment: @MarkViola you mean I cant split the integral in two ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  This is, in fact, the way one can prove the residue theorem.  Contour deformation is possible due to Cauchy's integral theorem.

Comment: Your way is perfectly fine. In fact, I think it's better than using the Residue theorem, since calculating the residues of this function is easiest to do by doing essentially the same calculations you do. But then the residue theorem is just the long way around.

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition could help. Then apply Cauchy integral formula.